# When trying to fetch details from user which linked to another entity it gives StackOverflow Error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am trying to learn to hibernate for that I am trying to make an app where a user can add some products and when we fetch the user and call the products list it should fetch the products which are added by that particular user for that I have defined @OneToMany mapping between user and products but when I am trying to fetch the user which have some products with him it gives me `StackOverflow` Error but when I am calling a user with no products it works fine. here is my code please have a look and please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**UserModel.java**

```
package com.solitera.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="user_password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="user_email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="user_address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name="user_phone")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name="user_role")
    private Integer role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "addedBy" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//  @JoinColumn(name="added_by")
    private List<ProductModel> products;
    
        
    public UserModel() {
    }


    public UserModel(String name, String password, String email, String address, String phoneNumber, Integer role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.role = role;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Integer getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(Integer role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    public List<ProductModel> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<ProductModel> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"name\":\"" + name + "\", \"password\":\"" + password + "\", \"email\":\""
                + email + "\", \"address\":\"" + address + "\", \"phoneNumber\":\"" + phoneNumber + "\", \"role\":\""
                + role + "\", \"products\":\"" + products + "\"}";
    }   
    
}
```

**ProductModel.java**

```
package com.solitera.model;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name; 

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="added_by")
    private UserModel addedBy;

    @Column(name="price")
    private Integer price;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productid" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PictureModel> pictures;
    
    public ProductModel() {
    }


    public ProductModel(String name, UserModel addedBy, Integer price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserModel getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }
    public void setAddedBy(UserModel addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public List<PictureModel> getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }
    public void setPictures(List<PictureModel> pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"name\":\"" + name + "\", \"addedBy\":\"" + addedBy + "\", \"price\":\""
                + price + "\", \"pictures\":\"" + pictures + "\"}";
    }



    
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
 public UserModel getuser(UserModel userModel,EntityManager entityManager) {
     Boolean isIntMgr = false;
     
     if(entityManager == null) {
         entityManager = MyEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
         entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
         isIntMgr =true;
     }
     Integer id= 8;
     
     userModel = entityManager.find(UserModel.class,id);
     
     logger.info("The user Model for USer id 8 is : "+ userModel );
     logger.info("This are the products : " + userModel.getProducts());
//   for(ProductModel products : userModel.getProducts()) {
//       logger.info("This are the products : " + products);
//   }  
     if(isIntMgr) {
         entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
     }
     return userModel;
 }
```

**Console**

```
04:09:2020 00:02:38 [LogHelper] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: my_test_eCommerce
    ...]
04:09:2020 00:02:38 [Version] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.2.Final}
04:09:2020 00:02:38 [Environment] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
04:09:2020 00:02:39 [Version] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
[main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
04:09:2020 00:02:39 [Dialect] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Hibernate: 
    select
        usermodel0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_address as user_add2_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_email as user_ema3_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_name as user_nam4_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_password as user_pas5_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_phone as user_pho6_2_0_,
        usermodel0_.user_role as user_rol7_2_0_ 
    from
        user usermodel0_ 
    where
        usermodel0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        products0_.added_by as added_by4_1_0_,
        products0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        products0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        products0_.added_by as added_by4_1_1_,
        products0_.name as name2_1_1_,
        products0_.price as price3_1_1_ 
    from
        products products0_ 
    where
        products0_.added_by=?
04:09:2020 00:02:40 [UserServiceImpl] --------------------Finally in Main ---------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:441)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:1165)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2801)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at com.solitera.model.ProductModel.toString(ProductModel.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2801)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `products` from `UserModel.toString()`

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"name\":\"" + name + "\", \"password\":\"" + password + "\", \"email\":\""
                + email + "\", \"address\":\"" + address + "\", \"phoneNumber\":\"" + phoneNumber + "\", \"role\":\""
                + role + "\"}";
    }
```

There's as stackoverflow error because the user's toString call the product's toString and so on.